# How to ask Terminator preference menu?

Tags: gnome-terminator

I'm a big fan of [Terminator](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator). By default, the preferences menu is accessible by a right click on the terminal. I just configured Terminator to do a copy paste on right click (similar like Putty).

Unfortunately, that makes the preferences menu is not accessible anymore. What is the solution?

Comment: Check please if this menu will be accessible by pressing `Shift` + `F10` keys.

Comment: Ahh yep that solves my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Middle click in Terminator works like right one in Putty
You may want to not redefine ))

Comment: Excellent answer to another question: "Where in the world do you find the Preferences menu?!"  :)

Answer (score 32):

It's the (awkward) <kbd>shift</kbd>+middle-click combo that brings up Terminator context menu for me when `putty_paste_style = True`.

This is in contrast to the docs, both the terminator_config manpage and the [online manual](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/preferences.html?highlight=putty), which state middle-click alone will bring up the Context Menu.

```
$ terminator --version
terminator 1.91

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

The mentioned <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> combo also works, but also stuffs garbage (;2~) onto the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The middle-click on the mouse does, indeed, work and can bring up the context menu. However, what is probably missing from the manual is the fact that it requires a DOUBLE click of the middle mouse button (basically your scroll wheel).

Here are the exact instructions:

1. Open/Start Terminator.
2. Place your mouse pointer anywhere (e.g. the middle) within the open
   Terminator window.
3. Double click the middle mouse button (scroll wheel).
4. Select "Preferences" from the drop-down that pops up on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Linux Mint 19.2 and I was on a laptop with only a track-pad (thus no middle click), so to fix this I editing `~/.config/terminator/config`. Just find `putty_paste_style` and make it equal "False". Save the file and restart terminator.

```
$ vim ~/.config/terminator/config
...
[global_config]
  putty_paste_style = True  ##<<< change this to "False"
[keybindings]
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      parent = window0
      type = Terminal
    [[[window0]]]
      parent = ""
      type = Window
[plugins]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    background_darkness = 0.75
    background_type = transparent
    copy_on_selection = True
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
    scroll_on_keystroke = False
    scrollback_infinite = True
```

Comment: I wish we could shift + right click to show the context menu or paste.

Answer (score 0):

While middle click and editing the terminator config file may work, you can also **delete** the entire config file by running:

`sudo rm -rf  ~/.config/terminator`

**This deletes ALL of your preferences**. Terminator generates a new preference file when it relaunches. Worked fine in my case.